# sum with condition in django query

Tags: mysql, django

We want to wrtie this query in django please

```
SELECT sum(recommended='1') AS YES,sum(recommended='0') AS NO FROM `rating` WHERE applied_users = 32500
```

we have no idea how to use in sum "= 1"

```
Rating.objects.filter(applied_id = 32500).aggregate(YES=Sum('recommended'))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use aggregate with case in django, it will return you single result with annotate it will return you a multiple records

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Case, When, IntegerField

Rating.objects.filter(applied_id = 32500)
    .aggregate(
        yes=Sum(
            Case(
                When(recommended='1', then=1), 
                output_field=IntegerField()
            ) 
        ),
        no=Sum(
            Case(
                When(recommended=0,then=1),
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

First refer this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/

```
    from django.db.models import Sum, Case, When, IntegerField

    OR 

    from django.db.models.aggregates import Sum
    from django.db.models.expressions import Case, When

    ratings = Rating.objects
.annotate(yes_count=Sum(Case(When(recommended='1', then=1),output_field=IntegerField())))
.annotate(no_count=Sum(Case(When(recommended='0', then=1),output_field=IntegerField())))
.filter(applied_id = 32500)
```